# Docker-Compose publishing ports on Host computer Nodejs + Express

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose

I have built a docker-compose file and want to access my nodejs app on `localhost:3000` from my host computer but publishing the ports doesn't seem to be working.

When I run compose-up everything seems to be working fine and I get the confirmation `Listening on port 3000`. However when I go to `localhost:3000` from a browser as well as `curl` I get a not found or timeout response.

Am I missing something here?

My NodeJS server:

```
var server = app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

My Docker-Compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    api:
      image: baum-test:v0
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      networks:
        - webnet
    mongodb:
     image: mongo:latest
     ports:
       - "27017:27017"
     volumes:
       - ./data:/data
     deploy:
       placement:
         constraints: [node.role == manager]
     networks:
       - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: You have "constraints: [node.role == manager]" are you using docker swarm or is that simply copy pasted from somewhere? Could you try 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost?

Comment: I was testing out the features of swarm but forgot to delete it from my compose-file. I will try and see if that helps.

Comment: Your compose file looks good. I can't think of another reason why it shouldn't be workng

Comment: Hmm well I tried bashing into the container and running curl from there and it seems to work just fine so am not sure what is happening here

Comment: what does docker ps return? Does it list the published port?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this using `docker stack deploy` command then you can  `"constraints: [node.role == manager]"` in your `docker-compose.yml`. If you used `docker-compose up` command to get the composition up then you are using Swarm features of the compose file but on docker-compose. Remove the below section completely

```
 deploy:
   placement:
     constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Comment: I did this and still am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Since I am running docker tools for windows (the old version without hyper-v) I had to manually declare the Docker VM Image IP address as it wasn't binding to localhost.